# Get first row from repeater field within loop

Tags: php, wordpress, loops, advanced-custom-fields

I am making a WP-site, using Advanced Custom Fields.
On one page I want to echo a loop with all the posts that has the category "Studio". Then I want to show the first image from the sub field named "studio_project_dia_img".
I can get all image from the repeater_field to show, however not just the first

This code works (only it echoes all rows from the repeater field):

```
    <div <?php post_class() ?> id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>">

        <li class="thumbs">
            <a href="studio-single.html" class="clearfix">
            <?php if (get_field('studio_project_dia')) : while(has_sub_field('studio_project_dia')): ?>

                    <img src="<?php echo get_sub_field('studio_project_dia_img', $post->ID); ?>" />
            <?php endwhile; endif; ?>
                    <div class="thumbsText">
                        <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
                        <h3><?php the_tags( 'Tags: ', '&nbsp;/&nbsp; ', ''); ?></h3>
                    </div>
            </a>



        </div>

        <?php edit_post_link('Edit this entry','','.'); ?>

    </div>

<?php endwhile; endif; ?>
```

this code doesn't:

```
    <div <?php post_class() ?> id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>">

        <li class="thumbs">
            <a href="studio-single.html" class="clearfix">
            <?php if (get_field('studio_project_dia')) : while(has_sub_field('studio_project_dia')): ?>
                    <?php
                        $rows = get_sub_field('studio_project_dia_img', $post->ID);
                        $first_row = $rows[0];
                        $first_row_image = $first_row['studio_project_dia_img'];

                        $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $first_row_image, 'full' );
                    // url = $image[0];
                    // width = $image[1];
                    // height = $image[2];
                    ?>
                    <img src="<?php echo $image[0] ?>" />
            <?php endwhile; endif; ?>
                    <div class="thumbsText">
                        <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
                        <h3><?php the_tags( 'Tags: ', '&nbsp;/&nbsp; ', ''); ?></h3>
                    </div>
            </a>



        </div>

        <?php edit_post_link('Edit this entry','','.'); ?>

    </div>

<?php endwhile; endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your first code, add `break;` after 'img' tag like this:

```
<?php if (get_field('studio_project_dia')) : while(has_sub_field('studio_project_dia')): ?>
    <img src="<?php echo get_sub_field('studio_project_dia_img', $post->ID); ?>" />
<?php break; endwhile; endif; ?>
```

With `break`, the `while` loop will stop.

Comment: This only echoes the text "break;" between each image.
However if you do this it works:
`<?php if (get_field('studio_project_dia')) : while(has_sub_field('studio_project_dia')): ?>
    <img src="<?php echo get_sub_field('studio_project_dia_img', $post->ID); ?>" />
    
<?php break; endwhile; endif; ?>`

Comment: Of course, was that I wanted to write. :) I modifed my answer. thanks for you return. :)

Comment: because I have corrected my mistake inattention thanks to you, and I am polite. ;)

Answer (score 1):

See above, only:

```
<?php if (get_field('studio_project_dia')) : while(has_sub_field('studio_project_dia')): ?>
    <img src="<?php echo get_sub_field('studio_project_dia_img', $post->ID); ?>" />

<?php break; endwhile; endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 
    if(have_rows('client_logo') ):
    while ( have_rows('client_logo') ) : the_row(); 
?>

<?php   
    $image = get_sub_field('logo');
    $size = 'full'; // (thumbnail, medium, large, full or custom size)

    if( $image ) {
        echo wp_get_attachment_image( $image, $size );
    } 
?>

<?php endwhile;
    else :
    // no rows found
    endif;
?>
```

I used this code to get the repeater field then the sub field and get it to display the image hope this helps you find your solution.